# Integration test non-ASP.NET IHost

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, automated-tests

I am building a .NET application that will listen to a RabbitMQ queue and respond to messages received from it. The application is built as a .NET Generic Host with an IHostedService handling the connection to the queue. Here is an extremely simplified version of this:

```
// ExampleHost/ExampleHostedService.cs

using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace ExampleHost;

public class ExampleHostedService : IHostedService
{
    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("StartAsync");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("StopAsync");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

```
// ExampleHost/Program.cs

using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace ExampleHost;

public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<ExampleHostedService>();
            })
            .Build();

        await host.RunAsync();
    }
}
```

This works just fine when running the application itself. However, I need to write integration tests for this application. The test should cause `StartAsync` and then `StopAsync` to be printed.

I first attempted the following:

```
// ExampleHost.Tests/ProgramTests.cs

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Xunit;

namespace ExampleHost.Tests;

public class ProgramTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void CanRun()
    {
        await using var webApplicationFactory
            = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>();
    }
}
```

This causes nothing to happen. However, I also tried this code:

```
// ExampleHost.Tests/ProgramTests.cs

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Xunit;

namespace ExampleHost.Tests;

public class ProgramTests
{
    [Fact]
    public async void CanRun()
    {
        await using var webApplicationFactory
            = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>();

        // Fails.
        webApplicationFactory
            .Services
            .GetRequiredService<ExampleHostedService>();
    }
}
```

This causes the following exception to be thrown:

```
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.91]     ExampleHost.Tests.ProgramTests.CanRun [FAIL]
  Failed ExampleHost.Tests.ProgramTests.CanRun [165 ms]
  Error Message:
   System.InvalidOperationException : No application configured. Please specify an application via IWebHostBuilder.UseStartup, IWebHostBuilder.Configure, or specifying the startup assembly via StartupAssemblyKey in the web host configuration.
  Stack Trace:
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at ExampleHost.Program.Main(String[] args) in /path/to/project/ExampleHost/Program.cs:line 17
   at ExampleHost.Program.<Main>(String[] args)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
   at System.Reflection.MethodInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.DeferredHostBuilder.DeferredHost.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Start(IHost host)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateHost(IHostBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.ConfigureHostBuilder(IHostBuilder hostBuilder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.EnsureServer()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.get_Services()
   at ExampleHost.Tests.ProgramTests.CanRun() in /path/to/project/ExampleHost.Tests/ProgramTests.cs:line 12
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
   at System.Reflection.MethodInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)

Failed!  - Failed:     1, Passed:     0, Skipped:     0, Total:     1, Duration: < 1 ms - ExampleHost.Tests.dll (net7.0)
```

It seems like WebApplicationFactory expects the host run by Program to be an ASP.NET server, which is not the case here. Can WebApplicationFactory be configured to be used with a .NET Generic Host? Or is there an equivalent of WebApplicationFactory for .NET Generic Host applications? Additionally, the .csproj files looks like this:

```
<!-- ExampleHost/ExampleHost.csproj -->

<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>11.0</LangVersion>
    <ImplicitUsings>disable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="7.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

```
<!-- ExampleHost.Tests/ExampleHost.Tests.csproj -->

<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>11.0</LangVersion>
    <ImplicitUsings>disable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <IsTestProject>true</IsTestProject>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing" Version="7.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.5">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.2.0">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ExampleHost\ExampleHost.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: You mean something like what Wolverine, MassTransit etc do? Post the actual code, not the simplified version. In the simplified version, all you have to do is create a host in the unit test, register the service and retrieve it with GetService. You don't need `WebApplicationFactory`. The job of `WebApplicationFactory` is to generate endpoints that test HttpClients can call in *integration* tests. In a controller unit test you can simply create a controller using its constructor and call the actions. Integration tests are needed to test binding, routing, etc

Comment: The real problem is how to "mock" RabbitMQ. In ASP.NET Core, the WAF can mock the server. You can't really mock RMQ though. If you have your own RMQ client abstraction, you could mock RMQ connections. If you use controller-like abstractions, the way MassTransit and Wolverine do, you can unit-test them without an actual RMQ instance.

Comment: You don't need to call `host.RunAsync()` to use DI, configuration etc.

Comment: I use the official RabbitMQ client `RabbitMQ.Client`. However, that's not especially relevant to the question. I have already set up RabbitMQ integration tests within an ASP.NET server, which are working. I understand that I can unit test ExampleHostedService but what I aim to do is to integration test the project and Program.cs would be included in that just as for an ASP.NET server.

Comment: I answered that already, and RMQ is *very* relevant. I use RMQ too, with MassTransit, Wolverine *and* direct RabbitMQ.Client. The whole point of the WebApplicationFactory is to create a proxy for the *server* with all the middleware with mock clients. In your case the server isn't Kestrel or IIS but RabbitMQ. Since you call RMQ directly, there's no middleware to hook up either. WAF won't help here.

Comment: Just ignore that I ever wrote "RabbitMQ" and imagine that my `IHostedService` is an arbitrary background service. For instance, I also have a similar application with another `IHostedService` that will poll a database at regular intervals and react to certain actions, which has nothing to do with RabbitMQ. What I want to achieve is to use the setup presented in Program.cs in an integration test, regardless of what `IHostedService` is being used.

Comment: I understand that WebApplicationFactory might not be the perfect fit so I'm asking for either an adjustment to WebApplicationFactory or an alternative to WebApplicationFactory for generic hosts.

Comment: The generic host has absolutely nothing to do with this question. No WebApplicationFactory is needed, which is why none exists.  You can simply create a host with all your existing code *in* the unit test. It will run just fine as long as you have a valid RabbitMQ server to connect to. It's the *server* that you need to mock, not the host

Comment: What would you do if you wanted to create integration tests for the database? Would you look for a *web* test server? You could just create the host and point it to a test database though. It's no different with RabbitMQ